# Sum for multiple keys

Tags: excel

I need to calculate population of my chosen cities. What formula will do that? I want my formula to be dynamic so that if I add more cities to my chosen cities it should add value(population) to the sum.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,E3:E5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works in Excel but in Google Sheets it sums as 0 any ideas why?

Comment: Because excel and Google sheets are two different apps and they are not always compatible. If you want a Google sheet answer ask another question and tag it appropriately.